# Django how to pass header on request in get_queryset

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using Django rest framework to pass a get request with a `query_param` like so:

### views.py

```
class PlanView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint which allows prices to be viewed or edited
    """

    serializer_class = PlanSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    # override method
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Plan.objects.all()
        size = self.request.query_params.get("size", None)
        if portion is not None:
            if size == "large":
                queryset = queryset.filter(Large=True)
            elif size == "small":
                queryset = queryset.filter(Small=False)
        return queryset
```

however, I set up an authentication class in settings.py like this:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
```

so that I can pass a header with a token in request. This works well when I test with a third party client like postman. however how can I pass an authorization token as header in the above view?

Comment: Query parameter as in `?size=...`?

Comment: If you've passed `size` as a `header` in the `http request` itself then you can get that by using `request.META['HEADER-NAME']`

Comment: @Sahil I did not pass size as header I passed it as a parameter. I want to pass authorization as header

Comment: If it's possible, please provide us with the request you are doing with POSTMAN so we can better understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass header as `size` in DRF and you want to access it in `get_qeryset()` method, then you will have to access it using `self.request.META['HTTP_SIZE']`

Comment: no I want to pass authorization as header not size how can I do that?

Comment: If your header is ```Authorization``` then it can be accessed using ```self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)```